# An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I was able to put, delete, and update and attribute with no problem of and item from my dynamoDB, but the problem that I am facing I when I want to update a Map inside of a List because it's seems that is concatenating a lot of maps and entering into a infinite loop and I got this error:
"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Nesting Levels have exceeded supported limits: Attributes in the item have nested levels beyond supported limit for key :incidencestoDel"

I'll give you and easy example in order that you can follow what I am doing and help me.
So imagine that I want update a list in dynamodb for the same list.

```
import json
import boto3
import random

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com ")
table = dynamodb.Table('dev_pharma-orders')

def handle_modify(record):
    print("Handling MODIFY Event")
#HERE IS WHERE I TAKE THE LIST FROM THE EVENT MODIFY
    incidences2 = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['incidences']['L']
#CREATE AN EMPTY LIST
    newIncidences=[]
#ADDING TO A LIST 
    for incidence in incidences2:
        newIncidences.append(incidence)

    table.update_item(
        Key={
#KEY OF THE TABLE
            "order_id":record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['order_id']['S']
        },
        UpdateExpression="set incidences=:incidencestoDel",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
#HERE IS WHERE I GOT THE INFINITE LOOP AND ERROR --> CONCATENATING A LOT OF MAPS 
            ':incidencestoDel': newIncidences
            }
        )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #1. Iterate over each record
    try:
        for record in event['Records']:
            #2. Handle event by type
            if record['eventName'] == 'MODIFY':
                handle_modify(record)
        return "Success!"
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        return "Error"
```

It seems that is entering all the time like infinite loop into the function "handle_modify(record):"

Here is one of the outputs:

> {'M': {'M': {'M': {'createTime': {'M': {'S': {'S': '2021-01-25T12:33:09+00:00'}}}, 'lastUpdate': {'M': {'S': {'S': '2021-01-25T12:33:15+00:00'}}}, 'origin': {'M': {'S': {'S': 'MANUAL'}}}, 'details': {'M': {'M': {'M': {'comments': {'M': {'S': {'S': 'Producto sin stock'}}}}}}}, 'type': {'M': {'S': {'S': 'OUT_OF_STOCK'}}}, 'resolution': {'M': {'M': {'M': {'action': {'M': {'S': {'S': 'USER_PHARMACY_CHANGED'}}}, 'description': {'M': {'NULL': {'BOOL': True}}}, 'resolutionTime': {'M': {'M': {'M': {}}}}}}}}, 'resolved': {'M': {'BOOL': {'BOOL': True}}}, 'status': {'M': {'S': {'S': 'RESOLVED'}}}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and resolved this error with the following approach:

convert the property with Map/List into a string using json.dumps
then when retrieving the item convert the string back to an object using json.loads